# Regex is matching a non-url

Tags: regex

I have written a regex to match URLs for the purposes of doing an str_replace() on posts in a comment system and replacing naked links with active, clickable links.

This works quite well:

```
(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\??(([a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*)&?)*\/?
```

matches URLs quite nicely, but it is failing on this line:

"I know that but your name is not on the list see... http://screencast.com/t/ccccccc"

It is matching the [see... http] part.

What's wrong?

Comment: How do you test that ? What language or library do you use ? (please look at the description of the tag you use)

Comment: That regex has a lot of problems (will match non-urls, will not fully match some URLs -- like `http://thisISatestxr.com?123`), the one you see is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the pattern that matches the protocol (the `http://` or `https://`) is optional. Also, the part of the pattern which is intended to match query of the URL (the part of the URL after the `?`).

Correct these two issues and it should work:

```
(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\??(&?([a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*))*
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28https%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%29%28%5B%5Cda-z%5C.-%5D%2B%29%5C.%28%5Ba-z%5C.%5D%7B2%2C6%7D%29%28%5B%5C%2F%5Cw%20%5C.-%5D%2a%29%2a%5C%3F%3F%28%26%3F%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2a%3D%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2a%29%29%2a&input=I%20know%20that%20but%20your%20name%20is%20not%20on%20the%20list%20see...%20http%3A%2F%2Fscreencast.com%2Ft%2Fccccccc)

But we can improve this a bit:

```
(https?://)[\da-z.-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+(\:\d+)?)(/[\w.-]*)*(\?\S+)?
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28https?://%29%5B%5Cda-z.-%5D%2b%28%5C.%5Ba-z0-9-%5D%2b%29%2b%28%5C%3a%5Cd%2b%29?%29%28/%5B%5Cw.-%5D%2a%29%2a%28%5C?%5CS%2b%29?&input=I%20know%20that%20but%20your%20name%20is%20not%20on%20the%20list%20see...%20http://screencast.com/t/ccccccc)

Of course, this is till an approximation. For a more detailed and complete pattern you should probably read [In search of the perfect URL validation regex](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex), where the author provides a number of patterns and shows their strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

```
(https?:\/\/)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\??(([a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*)&?)*\/?
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/pD0hD6)